# Replacing all \ with in string with / using javascript

Tags: javascript, join, replace, split

I am currently working on Javascript. 
I have a variable withich take value D:\Abc\xyz\mno\rst\uvw.inc
I need to replace all `\` with `/` from above variable.
I am getting the error: SyntaxError: unterminated string literal

Can someone please help me with this issue ?

Code is given below:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body> 
<table>
  <tr>
  <td>File Name </td>
  <td><Input type="text" id="file_name" size="100" onblur="getFilePath(this.value);">   </td>
  <td><Input type="text" id="for_file_name" size="100"></td>
 </tr>
</table>
<script>
 function getFilePath(var_input) {
  alert("Input: "+var_input);
  var myArray = var_input.split("\");
  var myStr = myArray.join('/');
   alert(myStr)
  }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should escape all backslash characters in strings:

```
var myArray = var_input.split('\\');
```

Also make sure that you don't use the Unicode quotes (`‘’`) instead of the normal quotes (`''`), as you have in `join` arguments:

```
// ----------------------v-v
var myStr = myArray.join(‘/’);
```

Comment: Thanks Vision, I have already corrected the question.
btw Thanks for your assistance. Cheers. Have a good day. :)

Comment: @raavan You are welcome. BTW, as proposed by #sergiomse it will be wise to use 'global' string replace instead of split-join combination, as it will work much faster.

Comment: Sure mate.. I will have a try on that too.. Cheers.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var_input = var_input.replace(/\\/g, "/");
```